# Visual Studio Python autocomplete not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, python-requests, intellisense

I've installed Visual Studio with Python language support. Python was installed separately with official installer from Python website. Visual Studio version = 16.8.1, Python 3 version = 3.9 (x86_x64)

I'm experiencing the following problem - autocomplete doesn't work for third-party installed packages such as requests. It doesn't work only in Visual Studio code editor but does work in the interactive shell. Why this is happening and what to do? Here is screenshots:

[Code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVxxU.png)

[Interactive shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU89X.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue as you described in my side. And also I have tested the issue with **Python 3.8** and **Python 3.7** and got the same behavior.

**However**, there is no direct evidence that VS IntelliSense cannot work for the additional installed python packages. And I am also curious about the differences between the **Interactive Shell** and **VS Code Editor**.

**Although** Interactive Shell is directly from **Python 3.9** itself while code editor is from **VS IDE**, they should be consistent on the same point. And not sure whether it might be an issue for VS Intellisense.

**Since** we cannot do more here, I [reported the issue on our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1256696/why-python-intellisense-in-vs-cannot-autocomplete.html). And you can vote it and add any comments if I did not describe the issue in detail so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention. And I hope the Team will give you a satisfactory reply. Besides, you can also contact with the [Python Team](https://www.python.org/community-landing/).

Answer (score 0):

Install Official Python extension on VS Code from Extensions Tab. Restart VS Code .Auto-complete shall work after that.